# SSIS sends error message as email

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis, dbf

SSIS sends error message as email while accessing .DBF file when it is locked. how to stop SSIS for sending an error during .DBF file is locked.

Thanx in advance

Comment: please share your code snippet so that anyone can help you better way

Comment: show picture which element of SSIS sends message